# oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection - python oracledb library

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, python-oracledb

I'm trying to connect oracle 11g with python

```
import oracledb
import os

user = 'system'
password = 'admin123'
port = 1521
service_name = 'xe'
oracle_server_addr = 'localhost'

conn_string = "{oracle_server_addr}:{port}/{service_name}".format(oracle_server_addr=oracle_server_addr, port=port, service_name=service_name)

print(conn_string)

with oracledb.connect(user=user, password=password, dsn=conn_string) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = """select sysdate from dual"""
        for r in cursor.execute(sql):
            print(r)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
conn_string: localhost:1521/xe

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 353, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 207, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._connect_phase_one
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 386, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_message
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 365, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_message
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/messages.pyx", line 1835, in oracledb.thin_impl.ConnectMessage.process
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/buffer.pyx", line 845, in oracledb.thin_impl.Buffer.read_uint32
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/packet.pyx", line 235, in oracledb.thin_impl.ReadBuffer._get_raw
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/packet.pyx", line 588, in oracledb.thin_impl.ReadBuffer.wait_for_packets_sync
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/transport.pyx", line 306, in oracledb.thin_impl.Transport.read_packet
  File "/home/acme/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oracledb/errors.py", line 162, in _raise_err
    raise exc_type(_Error(message)) from cause
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection
Help: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#dpy-4011

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/workspace/sql_ping/sql_ping.py", line 16, in <module>
    with oracledb.connect(user=user, password=password, dsn=conn_string) as conn:
  File "/home/acme/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oracledb/connection.py", line 1134, in connect
    return conn_class(dsn=dsn, pool=pool, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/acme/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oracledb/connection.py", line 523, in __init__
    impl.connect(params_impl)
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 449, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 445, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 411, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_params
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 392, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_description
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 358, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address
  File "/home/acme/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oracledb/errors.py", line 162, in _raise_err
    raise exc_type(_Error(message)) from cause
oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database (CONNECTION_ID=emkjRug2341/ymv7uTC0Bg==).
DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection
Help: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#dpy-4011
```

### Context (Environment)

Both (database and client app are in the same host)

- Database

  - Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit (localhost)
  - ubuntu
  - user = 'system'
  - password = 'admin123'
  - port = 1521
  - service_name = 'xe'
  - host = 'localhost' (I also tried with local ip and 127.0.0.1)
- App

  - ubuntu
  - python 3.10
  - oracledb 2.0.1 & 2.0.0
  - thin mode
- No firewall, proxy, antivirus, etc. All in my ubuntu localhost

### Attempts

##### # Works with java

In the same host, with the same database and thin mode, java <3 is able to connect without any problems. Code is [here](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/5998f84bc33b26f92d68f271157ac8a9#file-jdbc-snippets-oracle-md)

##### # Works with [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) database ide

[image]

##### # oracledb pip library downgrade

I tried with all the versions since 1.3.1 and the error is almost the same

https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/#history

**1.2.1, 1.3.2, 1.4.2**

```
oracledb.exceptions.NotSupportedError: DPY-3010: connections to this database server version are not supported by python-oracledb in thin mode
```

#### # disable_oob= True

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73281007/3957754) answer but the error is the same

#### # Similar unsolved questions

- [DPY-4011: the database or network closed connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76308017/dpy-4011-the-database-or-network-closed-connection)
- [DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73468766/dpy-4011-the-database-or-network-closed-the-connection)
- [Error Connecting virtual machine to oracle, using python (error DPY-4011)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73241118/error-connecting-virtual-machine-to-oracle-using-python-error-dpy-4011)
- [What does 'DPY-6001: cannot connect to database' mean with python-oracledb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72385508/what-does-dpy-6001-cannot-connect-to-database-mean-with-python-oracledb)
- [What does 'DPY-6005: cannot connect to database. Connection failed with "[Errno 61] Connection refused"' mean with python-oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72385533/what-does-dpy-6005-cannot-connect-to-database-connection-failed-with-errno)
- [Oracle DPY-6005: cannot connect to database. "[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73184530/oracle-dpy-6005-cannot-connect-to-database-winerror-10061-no-connection-cou)
- [python-oracledb thin client returns DPY-6005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74866786/python-oracledb-thin-client-returns-dpy-6005)
- https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/234

Comment: Are you saying that with version 2.0 you are getting DPY-4011 instead of DPY-3010?

Comment: Yes Anthony : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlhYw.png DPY-6005 and DPY-4011. Java, dbeaver and c# connects without problems

Comment: Oracle is  not certified to run on Ubuntu at all. You're not going to get reliable results and could easily run into errors like this with no recourse. Troubleshooting docs aren't going to help for an OS that doesn't support the software to begin with. I recommend installing the database on Oracle Linux instead. You should also consider using a version of the DB that is supported as well. 11gR1 hasn't been supported in over 15 years on *any* operating system.

Comment: Thanks pmdba. I know 11g is deprecated. But legacy companies still use it. Also java and c# are able to connect it without any issues

Comment: It is not just that 11g is deprecated; it is that **EVERY** Oracle version is unsupported on Ubuntu. Don't install it on Ubuntu. Oracle supports Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux and SUSE Linux Enterprise Server - install it on one of those (in a virtual machine inside Ubuntu if you need to).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot using thin mode as OracleDB does not support Oracle 11.

From the [Python OracleDB PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/):

> #### Dependencies and Interoperability
>
> - Python versions 3.7 through 3.12.
>
>   Prebuilt packages are available for these Python versions on Windows, on macOS and on Linux.
>
>   Source code is also available.
> - Oracle Client libraries are optional.
>
>   **Thin mode**: By default python-oracledb runs in a 'Thin' mode which connects directly to Oracle Database.
>
>   **Thick mode**: Some advanced Oracle Database functionality is currently only available when optional Oracle Client libraries are loaded by python-oracledb. Libraries are available in the free Oracle Instant Client packages. Python-oracledb can use Oracle Client libraries 11.2 through 21c.
> - Oracle Database
>
>   **Thin mode**: Oracle Database 12.1 (or later) is required.
>
>   **Thick mode**: Oracle Database 11.2 (or later) is required, depending on the Oracle Client library version. Oracle Database's standard client-server version interoperability allows connection to both older and newer databases. For example when python-oracledb uses Oracle Client 19c libraries, then it can connect to Oracle Database 11.2 or later.

Either use thick mode or upgrade your database to at least Oracle 12.1.

Comment: The limitation that Thick mode is required is because the resources required to support Thin mode for the very different 11g protocol, and for testing etc are not justifiable.  Using the traditional "thick mode" with client libraries which was required for tools in the 11g era of software works well.  It's better that we (Oracle) spend time improving the feature set of Thin mode for the majority of users.

Comment: There was a regression in 2.0 that prevented the error message raised in earlier versions: `DPY-3010: connections to this database server version are not supported by python-oracledb in thin mode`. This will be fixed in (likely) version 2.1.1.